# Inflating Class Error While Calling a SurfaceView from Main Xml

Tags: android, xml

I have been trying to add admob code to my app. I normally call a surfaceview directly from mainactivity.java.

Since I need to add the admob code to main xml I tried to call my surfaceview from main xml with a tag.

When I try to do that I get an Inflatin Class error at the beginning of the tag.   The solutions I found on stackoverflow did not help me so far.  Can someone help me?

### Here is mainactivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    /*mGLSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);*/

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gold_miner);
     mGLSurfaceView = (CCGLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.VIEWID);
```

### Here is Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

tools:context=".GoldMinerActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>



<view class="org.cocos2d.opengl.CCGLSurfaceView"
    android:id="@+id/VIEWID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

### And this is the LogCat Error

```
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.goldminer/org.goldminer.GoldMinerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class org.cocos2d.opengl.CCGLSurfaceView
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class org.cocos2d.opengl.CCGLSurfaceView
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1899)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at org.goldminer.GoldMinerActivity.onCreate(GoldMinerActivity.java:52)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     ... 11 more
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:561)
05-05 15:29:58.094: E/AndroidRuntime(8445):     ... 22 more
05-05 15:29:58.094: W/ActivityManager(2704):   Force finishing activity org.goldminer/.GoldMinerActivity
```

[Inflating Class Error](https://www.biliste.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/inflating-error.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace as text, not as an image.

Comment: @MikeM. I did edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `CCGLSurfaceView` cannot be instantiated from XML because it lacks the constructor

```
CCGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs);
```

Your options are

1) Create a class that extends `CCGLSurfaceView` that implements such constructor

2) Add it dynamically to the layout

The second approach would be:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GoldMinerActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in `onCreate`, after `setContentView`:

```
.
.
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.root);

// create the surfaceview
CCGLSurfaceView cocos = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);

// create the layout params (tweak this to your needs)
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

root.addView(cocos, 0, layoutParams);
.
.
```

The "0" in `addView` will cause your `SurfaceView` to be created behind the rest of Views, so the Ad is over it, however you maybe can use a Vertical `LinearLayout` as root layout, or create more elaborated `LayoutParams`,  so the AdView is below the `surfaceView` rather than on top of it.

Comment: I have followed the 2nd method you suggested. I want to thank you for your help. I have passed the previous problem. However when I put `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);` it says cannot resolve the symbol layoutparams and suggest me to change it with `(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)`. When I run the apk `mGLThread.surfaceCreated();` gives NullPointerException error.Is my edit of code correct? and what might return null for created surface?

Comment: Yeah, `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` is just fine, `MATCH_PARENT` is defined in all `LayoutParams` and is always `-1`. The other thing seems another unrelated problem to me, `surfaceCreated` is a callback you get when the surface to draw has been created by the system. I'd need more context to be able to guess what's going on ! Did it work before adding the ad?

Comment: Yes it was working fine before trying to modify and add the admob code. I added all the files and log.txt in the folder. If you get a chance to look at them It would make me so happy. here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/52dfdqukzxic5y6/AAB86la5TfA65PyAUNQQzKwSa?dl=0)

Comment: I think you have deleted important stuff in the process. The error is caused because you haven't set a `Renderer` for the  `SurfaceView`. From the GLSurfaceView documentation: **Initializing GLSurfaceView:  All you have to do to initialize a GLSurfaceView is call `setRenderer(Renderer)`** . I can't see any setRenderer on your initialization !

Comment: In the original working version we had `mGLSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this)` now we changed it with `CCGLSurfaceView cocos = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);` this is the only difference I could see in the versions of code. In your version of code how can I create `mGLSurfaceView`? I have been banging my head to the wall for 1 month on this code. You helped me a lot. I sense that this is the last bug I need to solve. Thank you so much.